# Can I draw a custom shape with a path and then fill it with a linear fill via xml?

Tags: android, xml-drawable, shapedrawable

Is it possible for me to draw a path in XML and fill it with a linear fade and put it as a background drawable for a LinearLayout or Button?

Cheers